# Opencart Warning: implode(): invalid arguments passed admin/controller/common/header.php

Tags: opencart2.x

I have installed opencart 2.0.3.1, When I login first time. i got some warnings. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Warning:
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /var/www/html/ramaneeyam/upload/admin/controller/common/header.php on line 58

I have referred some links in opencart forum. But not able to fix it.

Comment: Open `admin/controller/common/header.php` and paste line 58 here.

Comment: Was that a fresh installation?

Comment: Yes this is fresh installation

Comment: @AliZia, $data['order_status_total'] = $this->model_sale_order->getTotalOrders(array('filter_order_status' => implode(',', $this->config->get('config_processing_status'))));

Comment: Can you `print_r` this right above your code? `$this->config->get('config_processing_status')`